# Entity Framework - Multiple CLR Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error when executing one one of my LINQ queries

> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR
>   types match the EDM type 'Product'. Previously found CLR type
>   'TF.MyProject.DAL.Product, newly found CLR type
>   'TF.MyProject.DTO.Product'.

The Entity Framework generated class and the DTO object both are under their own namespace. This has worked previously and below is what I have tried so far...

1. Regenerated the EDMX Model
2. Removed and Created a new EDMX Model
3. Run Custom Tool to generate the Template files
4. Ensure all projects within the solution are using the same Entity Framework version.

Entity Framework version: 6.1.3

Below is how my current project is set up

MyProject

- /DAL/MyProjectModel.edmx
- /DTO/Product.cs

Any idea or suggestions will be helpful. This has worked in my previous projects with version 6. Not sure if it is specific to a version within release 6..

Note: Moving the DAL to a project of its own resolves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes with the same name `Product`. Entity Framework uses **Class Names** only, irrespective of namespaces or files where it is declared. The error message clearly says you have two Product classes, one in `TF.MyProject.DAL` namespace and another one in `TF.MyProject.DTO`.

Try renaming on of these `Product` classes to some other name and try again.

Comment: Well if I move the DAL to a project of its own then it resolves the problem